# Scala: Can I declare a public field that will not generate getters and setters when compiled?

Tags: scala

In Scala when you declare a val or a var, Scala will automatically generate a private field and the getters and setters for you when compiled to bytecode.

E.g.

```
class myClass {
    val name = "My Name"
}
```

will compile to create the equivalent

```
class myClass {
    private string name;
    public string name();
    public void name_$eq(string);
}
```

Where name() and name_$eq are the getters and setters for the private string name.

I know you can force it to not provide the getters and setters for private fields by declaring them as private[this] val/var blah, but I need to be able to create a public field that doesn't generate getters and setters when compiled.

Is this even possible in Scala?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't create a setter for vals

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<del>The generated class does not contain getters or setters as can be seen in the sample you provided.</del> The generated classes does not contain java bean getters or setters. To actually make the compiler generate `getX` and `setX` methods for a `var` you need to annotate that variable with `@BeanProperty`.

If you would like to have a public field accessible from java I think you are out of luck unfortunately. Atleast, I have not seen a way to accomplish that only using scala.

You could accomplish it by mixing scala and java. With a java class like:

```
public abstract class JavaClassWithPublicField {
   public String name = "My name";
}
```

And then in your scala code inherit that class:

```
class ScalaClassWithPubilcField extends JavaClassWithPublicField
```

That's likely the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: Updated answere since I realized you might be able to solve the problem by mixing java and scala.

Comment: A "getter" is not a method called `getX`, nor is a "setter" a method called `setX`. Java has that convention for getters and setters names due to syntactical limitations of the language. Scala has not, and the getter is called `x` while the setter is called `x_=` (or `x_$eq` as seen from Java).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @DanielC.Sobral I altered the answere a bit to make that distinction clearer. The first part might be a bit of topic now though...

Comment: I think you're right and the only way to do it is by mixing the Scala with Java.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you want to force the way your attribute is represented because you're accessing from Java. (If you're trying to "optimise" your byte code by getting rid of the getter then you're wasting your time, the VM will quickly inline them.) Unfortunately for you, to keep the door as wide open as possible for future improvements, the Scala specs [don't specify how Scala code should be translated to byte code](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/265). This means that even if you find a trick that works for a given version of Scala, it's not guaranteed to work in subsequent versions.

The recommended approach in these cases is to write the Java-visible code in Java and then have a small glue class written in Scala - something like the answer given by @Emil is great.