# public class member in scala class not accessible in java class

Tags: java, scala

I'm learning scala, and to practice, I have started to convert some of my existing java classes into scala, so I can also learn about scala-java inter-op. Following is my project setup:

**Scala class** :

```
@Entity
class DemoBeanScala{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @BeanProperty
    var Id: Long= _

    @BeanProperty
    var str: String= _

    @BeanProperty
    var num: Int = _

    @BeanProperty
    var d:Double = _

    def testFunc(printText: () => Unit){
      printText()
    }

    val pr = () => {
      println("functional programming test")
    }
}
```

**Java class**(extract):

```
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public DemoBeanScala demo(@RequestParam(value="id") Long Id, @RequestParam(value="str") String str, @RequestParam(value="num") int num, @RequestParam(value="d") double d)
{
    DemoBeanScala dbs = new DemoBeanScala();
    dbs.setId(123456);
    dbs.setStr("sample text");
    dbs.setNum(1);
    dbs.setD(2.1);
    dbs.testFunc(dbs.pr);
    return dbs;
}
```

From what I have learnt, **pr** in **DemoBeanScala** class should be accessible in my java class, since no modifier is declared before it. But, after maven compilation(using **scala:compile**) and running java code, I'm getting an error saying that pr is private in DemoBeanScala class. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your compiled class in [javap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html), you will see somethign like this :

```java
public class DemoBeanScala {
  private final scala.Function0<scala.runtime.BoxedUnit> pr;
  public scala.Function0<scala.runtime.BoxedUnit> pr();
  // And some other stuff...
}
```

You will notice two important difference with Java :

- Scala respects the [uniform access principle](http://docs.scala-lang.org/glossary/#uniform-access-principle), so there is no difference between calling a method without a parameter list or accessing a property. To make that work, the scala compiler will generate a public accessor method and a private field to represent a public property.
- Java doesn't have methods without a parameter list: they always have at least an empty parameter list.

So, from Java, you need to access the `pr` property with `dbs.pr()`, not `dbs.pr` (or generate a Java-style getter with `@BeanProperty`, as you did for your other properties, and access it as `dbs.getPr()`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. using dbs.pr() worked. I'm even more intrigued about java-scala inter-op than I was before :)

Answer (score 1):

When you add `@BeanProperty` that particular property is not visible in java class, only the generated public setters and getters are available or you may access scala like setter (`pr_$eq()`) and getter (`pr()`).

I could not find a proper reference, but the following links may helpful for you, they are not directly related to this question, but they will help you understanding.

[Scala: Can I declare a public field that will not generate getters and setters when compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347384/scala-can-i-declare-a-public-field-that-will-not-generate-getters-and-setters-w)
https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4481

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and the reference :)